# Sequelize associations hasOne, belongsTo

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

The problem is that I can not get working the relation hasOne, which does not eager load the state type object.

All the queries are done on existing tables.

Here is the customer table, whats important is the `cst_state_type` field:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    return sequelize.define('customer', {

        customer: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: true,
            validate: {
                isNumeric: true
            }
        },
        first_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            validate: {
                isAlphanumeric: true
            }
        },
        last_name: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        identity_code: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: true,
            validate: {
                isNumeric: true
            }
        },
        note: DataTypes.STRING(1000),
        birth_date: DataTypes.DATE,


        created_by: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        updated_by: DataTypes.INTEGER,

        cst_type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        cst_state_type:  {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        }

    }, {
        tableName: 'customer',

        updatedAt: 'updated',
        createdAt: 'created',
        timestamps: true
    });
};
```

cst_state_type table:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    return sequelize.define('StateType', {

        cst_state_type: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            validate: {
            }
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING(100),
    }, {
        tableName: 'cst_state_type',
        timestamps: false
    });
};
```

How the relations are described:

```
  global.db.Customer.hasOne(global.db.StateType, {
    foreignKey: 'cst_state_type',
    as: 'state_type'
  });

  global.db.StateType.belongsTo(global.db.Customer, {
    foreignKey: 'cst_state_type'
  });
```

And creating eager loading query:

```
    db.Customer.findAll( {
        include: [
            { model: db.Address, as: 'addresses' },
            { model: db.StateType, as: 'state_type' }
        ]
    })
        .success(function (customers) {
            res.json(200, customers);
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            res.json(500, { msg: error });
        });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the error is in your associations somewhere. From the way you described your table structure, the assocations should look something like this:

```
global.db.Customer.belongsTo(global.db.StateType, {
    foreignKey: 'cst_state_type',
    as: 'state_type'
});

global.db.StateType.hasMany(global.db.Customer, {
    foreignKey: 'cst_state_type'
});
```

As i understand it, the same state can be assigned to many customers, therefore `StateType.hasMany`. The relation from customer -> statetype is a "back-assocation", meaning that the foreign key is in the customer table. For that you need `belongsTo`

Answer (score 29):

Thanks for you answer, it helped me a lot. You can also add the relations directly in your model by using classmethods. I added a example below, hope this helps!

**User** Model (file)

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var User = sequelize.define(
        'User', {
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            }
        },
        {
            classMethods:{
                associate:function(models){
                    User.hasMany(models.Comment, { foreignKey: 'userId'} );
                }
            }
        }

    );
    return User;
};
```

**Comment** Model (file):

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var Comment = sequelize.define(
        'Comment', {
            text: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            }
        },
        {
            classMethods:{
                associate:function(models){
                    Comment.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey:'userId'} );
                }
            }
        }

    );
    return Comment;
};
```

You don't have to set the foreignkey, sequelize will handle it if you don't specify the foreignkeys.

Then in the query:

```
models.Comment.find({
        where: { id: id },
        include: [
            models.User
        ],
        limit: 1
    })
```

Comment: Excellent example! Simple and functional.

Comment: upvoted! do you have to add BOTH user.hasMany and Comments.belongsTo or one of them will suffice? if one then which one?